# MultiValue array from CSV Import - Exchange Permissions

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Attempting to import a CSV, which has exchange permissions such as:

```
Folder,User,Permissions
Folder1,TheUser,PERM1 PERM2 PERM3 PERM4
```

I'm trying to firstly import those value, as one individual column of the CSV. How does one achieve that for the Permissions column?
Secondly, trying to apply those permissions to a `Add-PublicFolderClientPermission` cmdlet. However I try to import the Perms, I get an error stating the Permissions are not of Type Exchange permissions etc

Could anyone assist please?

Comment: Can you share your code so we can assist with that. Referencing a column you can dot reference the property. `$MyCSVVariable.User`

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your CSV has valid entries for folder identities, usernames, and mailbox folder access rights:

```
# Import the csv and look at the first row:
$csv = Import-CSV C:\path\to\file.csv
$csv[0]|fl  

Folder      : \TestParent\TestChild
User        : john.smith
Permissions : ReadItems CreateItems EditOwnedItems
```

Your example doesn't have the slashes required for folder IDs, so make sure you can actually resolve all the public folders in your CSV:

```
# Should not return any errors
$csv | Select -Unique -Expand Folder | %{Get-PublicFolder $_}
```

If you're good there, then try this out:

```
Foreach ($Row in $CSV) {

  # Convert the rights to an object we can use:
  $Rights = $Row.Permissions -split ' ' | Foreach {
    [Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.MailboxFolderAccessRight]::new($_)}

  # Add rights entry to target folder
  Get-PublicFolder $Row.Folder | Add-PublicFolderClientPermission -User $Row.User -AccessRights $Rights
}
```